# Why am I getting this odd and hidden device manager warning when I open device manager as a non-admin user?

Tags: windows-10

Whenever I open the device manager as a non-admin user, it pops up a warning which appears behind all the other windows. I hear a ding but I don't see the popup until I minimize all the other windows.

It isn't until I click “OK” on this window that the device manager pops up.

Is there some setting that causes this popup to appear on top of the other Windows?

Comment: No absolute fix. Try restarting and add see if it works correctly.

Comment: I believe this is 100% normal, albeit undesired. I've had it many times & it happens with other apps too sometimes

Comment: Guess I have to windows-M after launching.